# Could I have unwittingly run over a jinn while driving?

Tags: jinn

Maybe this is a strange question, but...

> The Quran says that the jinn were created from a smokeless and "scorching fire", but are also physical in nature, being **able to interact in a tactile manner with people and objects and likewise be acted upon**. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn))

It may be that this is not correct (indeed, it's possible my [qareen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qareen) [companion jinn] may have read the Wikipedia page along with me, and done the jinn equivalent of a facepalm, thinking "this is all wrong").  If it is accurate, it seems reasonable to think that e.g. when driving, I might have unwittingly run over a jinn (or maybe many).  But maybe that's not how it works.

**Question**:  Could I have unwittingly run over a jinn while driving?

I don't want to be hurting jinn, unintentionally or not.

I know next to nothing about the jinn; I had never heard of them until I converted to Islam a few months back.  Googling about the jinn leads to a lot of webpages which seem significantly embellished.

Indeed, it seems that as a species, we don't know much about the jinn.  So it may be the best answer to this question is simply "we don't know" and identify how scholars are uncertain or in disagreement about it.

Comment: No, you could have not. They are of different dimension.

Comment: what i think the majirity of informations about jinn in islamic cultues are coming from Experiences and stories even sahaba and tabiin and ai'ima had stories with jinn !

Comment: Rebecca, this is not a video game, you can't have a "companion jinn" in real life with whom you can communicate, it's not how this works

Answer (score 1):

Running over a jinn while driving is possible.

I take the above opinion from proof where jinn enters humans. When a human unintentionally urinates on them.

> Ibn Taymiyah said: “When the jinn touch a person with epilepsy, it may be because of desire or love, just as happens between one human and another… or it may – as is usually the case – be because of hatred and punishment, such as when a person has harmed them or they think that he has harmed them deliberately, either by urinating on them or pouring hot water on them or killing them, even if the person did that unknowingly. There are ignorant and wrongdoing ones among the jinn who may punish a person more than he deserves, or they may be playing with him and mistreating him, like foolish people among mankind.”

Reference: https://islamqa.info/en/1819